# Find current work shift from table

Tags: mysql, vb.net, calendar, schedule

I'm creating a table for shift times, each day has it's own start/end time.  The table below only shows Sunday & Monday, but the actual table will have 7 days.  I want to be able to display the current shift (desc) based on current time.  This is straight forward until I get to 3rd shift, specifically past midnight.  If it's 5am Monday, that is actually 3rd shift Sunday.  How can I go about this, either to make a table work, or if there might be a better way to go about it?

```
ID  Desc Sunday_Start  Sunday_End  Monday_Start  Monday_End
1   1st  07:00:00      15:00:00    07:00:00      15:00:00
2   2nd  15:00:00      23:00:00    15:00:00      23:00:00
3   3rd  23:00:00      07:00:00    23:00:00      07:00:00
```

I noticed this post, 
[DateTime range issue when time passes midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38450288/datetime-range-issue-when-time-passes-midnight), but it looks like it is primarily for a repeatable shift from day to day.

The customer really wants each day to be different.  I haven't decided if I will do in MySQL or just XML.  So, one question, is there a better way to do this?  I was searching for a calendar and using a repeating appointment, but I didn't see anything free that was worthwhile.  Anyone have any insight on this?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 vb.net & MySQL.

Comment: You probably want to save the data as Start Time and Shift Length instead of Shift_End. You can still display it as times, but it will make the math a tad easier.

Comment: You should also have one row each day/shift combination.

Comment: I had the wrong link, I will use TimeSpan, so the math isn't the problem.  Also, not sure row/table arrangement will make much difference.  Thanks Trevor & Paul for the responses but not much help on my post.

Comment: We did answer your question James. If you have a simple table with one shift per row, and a day, starttime and duration. it is a simple matter to find out which row is current given the current day and time.

Comment: As for which format you save it in... that's a much wider question beyond the scope of this forum... esp when u have to take maintenance and staff familiarization into account.

Comment: The point of (good) database design is to get rid of repeating columns like that.

Comment: Yes, normalise your design. A database table is not a spreadsheet

Comment: I guess I'm having a hard time visualizing this.  If anyone is willing to take a few minutes to give me a visual aid then maybe I might get a kick start.  I really need to get my hands on best practice for DB.  Where I work I have nobody to ask, so I spend a lot of time searching forums.  So, if anyone can point me in the direction of a good read, please let me know.

Comment: Is this for defining work shifts or actual (employee ?) work times?   The mention of a calendar makes it sound one way, other things make it sound otherwise.

Comment: It's for work shifts.  I am collecting data with time stamps.  I then want to generate shift reports.  So, first I need to define the shifts.  I would like to have a form where they can add or edit shift information, which will basically be when the shift starts and ends.  Also, be able to print the reports automatically when the current shift ends.

Answer (score 0):

Your shift table should be like this...

[image]

Unlike excel, databases should always have ONE record (Row) per "Item"...

Note I used Shift_Length instead of Shift_End. Shift_Length is in hours. Shift_End can therefore be calculated from the two.

Now searching for the current shift simply involves determining if the current day & time is within Shift_Length of the indicated day and Start_Time.

Comment: I can agree with this, but I still don't see how this helps me determine the shift when the midnight boundary is passed.  Let's assume 7 days in a week, Sunday = 0 and Saturday = 6, if it's Monday then that is 1.  If it's Tuesday 1am, that is still Monday 3rd shift, however, the day value is 2.  So, is the suggestion to simply subtract 1 if we are in this period?  I guess that just seems clunky to me.  It's this midnight boundary that I'm having a hard time figuring out.

Comment: You still need to do a two step test.. one with todays day and if you get no match with that... check yesterdays day.

Comment: My problem with that is there will be times when there is no match, on the current day, and possibly the day before.  In those cases not havng a match doesn't mean look at the previous day.  The shift times are not always seamless.  The customer may have 1st and 3rd shift only, not sure why, but I need to think all of possibilities on this

Comment: If there is a down time... that method will find it no issue. The real concern is overlapping shifts... then u r screwed.